# How to know which entity is called just from the path given by RouterInterface in Symfony 5?

Tags: symfony5

I d like to retrieve a class just from a "path" which is given by RouterInterface with

> $router->getRouteCollection()

in case there is a param "slug" in it, to instantiate another Object for each entity found in this class.
Ex:
/admin/dummy/edit/{slug}
Is there a way to know just from this string that the class injected in the controller is Dummy::class.
And I can also get the controller
App\Controller\AdminController\DummyController::edit

Comment: That's pretty much what the framework's `ControllerResolver`, [`ArgumentResolvers`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/argument_value_resolver.html) and [`ParamConverters`](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html#doctrine-converter) already do. Have a look to the [available events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-controller) where you can hook up.

Comment: Hello, thank you, but actually, it wasn't very clear, I would like to make a service which retrieve the routes with a certain pattern (the routes for the front), and create automatically an entity associated with that route (it s an idea for a SEO purpose), with router->getCollection() I obtain an array of the routes, "home_page" => "/" ; and from that I wish to retrieve the entity injected in the controller that generate the route, if there is one

Comment: You can still look into the classes I mentioned for inspiration, but they use [php's reflection functions]https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) if you want to look into that. Please, [edit] your question to add the relevant information of what you want to accomplish and any code you have attempted. You'll be more likely to get answers if we have something to go on.

Comment: Thank you so much, with your help I found what I searched, the key was the ReflectionClass with the good namespace.